# How would I make it so (if Sector[1]=="l" and BRCTerritories[1]==".":) brings up all the results in the table?

Tags: python, sql, sql-server-2008

```
print 'Content-Type: application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml'
print 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=BRC_Services.kml\n'
import _mssql
import cgi

fs = cgi.FieldStorage()

BRCTerritories=str(fs['BRCTerritories'].value)
Sector=str(fs['Sector'].value)

if BRCTerritories[1]==".":
    menusearch = {"BRC_Area":BRCTerritories[0:3],"Sector":str(fs['Sector'].value)}

else:
    menusearch = {"BRC_Territory":BRCTerritories[0:1],"Sector":str(fs['Sector'].value)} 

if BRCTerritories[1]=="l":
    menusearch = {"Sector":str(fs['Sector'].value)}

if Sector[1]=="l" and BRCTerritories[1]=="-":
    menusearch = {"BRC_Territory":BRCTerritories[0:1]}  

if Sector[1]=="l" and BRCTerritories[1]==".":
    menusearch = {"BRC_Area":BRCTerritories[0:3]}   

query='SELECT * FROM dbo.Services'

conn = _mssql.connect(server='gisdata', user='gisdata', password='gisdata', database='GISData')
addition=1

## KML Header

kmlheader = (
    '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n'
    '<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">\n'
    '<Document>\n'
    '<StyleMap id="msn_label">\n'
    '<Pair>\n'
    '<key>normal</key>\n'
    '<styleUrl>#sn_label</styleUrl>\n'
    '</Pair>\n'
    '<Pair>\n'
    '<key>highlight</key>\n'
    '<styleUrl>#sh_label</styleUrl>\n'
    '</Pair>\n'
    '</StyleMap>\n'

    '<Style id="sn_label">\n'
    '<LabelStyle>\n'
    '<scale>1</scale>\n'
    '</LabelStyle>\n'
    '<IconStyle><scale>1</scale><Icon><href>http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/placemark_circle.png</href></Icon></IconStyle>\n'
    '</Style>\n'

    '<Style id="sh_label">\n'
    '<LabelStyle>\n'
    '<scale>1</scale>\n'
    '</LabelStyle>\n'
    '<IconStyle><scale>2</scale><Icon><href>http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/placemark_circle.png</href></Icon></IconStyle>\n'
    '</Style>\n'
    )

name="<name>BRC Services Search Results</name>"

print kmlheader
print name

for term in menusearch:

    if addition==1:
        addition=0
        add= (
            " WHERE %s='%s'"
            ) %(term,menusearch[term])
    else:
        add= (
            " AND %s='%s'"
            ) %(term,menusearch[term])
    query=query+add

results = [ row for row in conn ] 

print "<Folder><name>BRC Services</name>"
print "<name><b>Search=</b>"
print menusearch
print "</name>"

for row in results:

    description = (
        '<h2>%s</h2><br /><br />\n'
        '<b>Postcode:</b> %s<br />\n'
        '<b>Sector:</b> %s<br />\n'
        '<b>Phone:</b> %s<br />\n'
        '<b>BRC_Territory:</b> %s<br />\n'
        '<b>BRC_Area:</b> %s<br />\n'   
        '<b>Web:</b> %s<br />\n'    
        ) %(row['Sector'],row['postcode'],row['Sector'],row['phone'],row['BRC_Territory'],row['BRC_Area'],row['web'])

    placemark = (
        '<Placemark>\n'
        '<name>%s</name>\n'
        '<description><![CDATA[%s]]></description>\n'
        '<styleUrl>#msn_label</styleUrl>\n'
        '<Style>\n'
        '<BalloonStyle>\n'
        '<color>ffffffff</color>'
        '<text><![CDATA[<font color="Black">$[description]</font>]]></text>'
        '</BalloonStyle>\n'
        '</Style>\n'
        '<Point>\n'
        '<coordinates>%s,%s</coordinates>\n'
        '</Point>\n'
        '</Placemark>\n\n'
        ) %(row['Sector'],description,row['Lat'],row['Lon'])
    print placemark

print "</Folder>"

kmlfooter = '</Document>\n</kml>'

print kmlfooter

conn.close
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the base string to this:

```
query='SELECT * FROM dbo.Services where 1=1'
```

Now you don't need the where initialization based on  "if addition=1" logic; you can just iterate all menu search terms as "And".

Test if the criteria are the given sentinel values, if so empty the set of menusearch terms, so nothing else gets appended.